# PySpark - Show a count of column data types in a dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How can I view the count of each data type in a Spark Dataframe like I would if I used a pandas dataframe?

For example, assuming df is a pandas dataframe:

```
>>> df.info(verbose=True)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
int_col      5 non-null int64
text_col     5 non-null object
float_col    5 non-null float64
**dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(1)**
memory usage: 200.0+ bytes
```

We can very clearly see the count of each data type.  How can I do something similar with a spark dataframe?  That is, how can see how many columns are float, how many columns are int, and how many columns are objects?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion!  Unfortunately, I'm not trying to count the # of missing values in each column.  Rather, I'm just trying to see how many columns are float, how many columns are int, and how many columns are objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use `collections.Counter`:

```python
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1.2, 'foo'), (2, 2.3, 'bar'), (None, 3.4, 'baz')],
    ["int_col", "float_col", "string_col"]
)

from collections import Counter
print(Counter((x[1] for x in df.dtypes)))
#Counter({'double': 1, 'bigint': 1, 'string': 1})
```

And there's also `pyspark.sql.DataFrame.describe()` method:

```python
df.describe().show()
+-------+------------------+------------------+----------+
|summary|           int_col|         float_col|string_col|
+-------+------------------+------------------+----------+
|  count|                 2|                 3|         3|
|   mean|               1.5|               2.3|      null|
| stddev|0.7071067811865476|1.0999999999999999|      null|
|    min|                 1|               1.2|       bar|
|    max|                 2|               3.4|       foo|
+-------+------------------+------------------+----------+
```

Notice that `int_col` has a `count` of 2, since one of the value is `null` in this example.

Answer (score 2):

The below code should get you your desired result

```
# create data frame 
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
[(1,'Y','Y',0,0,0,2,'Y','N','Y','Y'),
 (2,'N','Y',2,1,2,3,'N','Y','Y','N'),
 (3,'Y','N',3,1,0,0,'N','N','N','N'),
 (4,'N','Y',5,0,1,0,'N','N','N','Y'),
 (5,'Y','N',2,2,0,1,'Y','N','N','Y'),
 (6,'Y','Y',0,0,3,6,'Y','N','Y','N'),
 (7,'N','N',1,1,3,4,'N','Y','N','Y'),
 (8,'Y','Y',1,1,2,0,'Y','Y','N','N')
],
('id', 'compatible', 'product', 'ios', 'pc', 'other', 'devices', 'customer', 'subscriber', 'circle', 'smb')
)

# Find data types of data frame
datatypes_List = df.dtypes

# Querying datatypes_List gives you column and its data type as a tuple
datatypes_List
[('id', 'bigint'), ('compatible', 'string'), ('product', 'string'), ('ios', 'bigint'), ('pc', 'bigint'), ('other', 'bigint'), ('devices', 'bigint'), ('customer', 'string'), ('subscriber', 'string'), ('circle', 'string'), ('smb', 'string')]

# create empty dictonary to store output values
dict_count = {}

# Loop statement to count number of times the data type is present in the data frame
for x, y in datatypes_List:
    dict_count[y] = dict_count.get(y, 0) + 1


# query dict_count to find the number of times a data type is present in data frame
dict_count
```

Answer (score 1):

Either `printSchema`

```
import datetime

df = spark.createDataFrame([("", 1.0, 1, True, datetime.datetime.now())])
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- _3: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _4: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- _5: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

or check `dtypes`

```
df.dtypes

[('_1', 'string'),
 ('_2', 'double'),
 ('_3', 'bigint'),
 ('_4', 'boolean'),
 ('_5', 'timestamp')]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion!  Unfortunately, my dataframe contains thousands of columns so it's not feasible for me to look through each one.  Is there a way I can sum up the data types?